# Display value from related table in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a model with an MVC 5 Internet Application and then added in ADO.Net Entity Data Model > Code first from Database. **I have added a foreign key in a newly created table linking to the ID in the AspNetUsers table.**

I created the default Controller then the View with Entity Framework and everything displayed fine.

The username was displaying in a dropdown with the below code

```
@Html.DropDownList("UserID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

So changed it to the below in order to have it as a read-only field

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserID, "Username", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserID)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Used the answer on this thread as a guide [Display EditorFor() value as Read-Only on MVC View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593172/display-editorfor-value-as-read-only-on-mvc-view) Im using VS 2013 MVC 5 plus all updates. How could i display the user name? Would i need to adjust the Controller with a new method? (I have UserId above as i was hoping some value to display in the amended code so i could narrow down where the issue is)

As requested

```
public partial class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseContext() : base("name=BaseContext") {}

    public virtual DbSet<C__MigrationHistory> C__MigrationHistory { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<InternationalOffice> InternationalOffices { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<NewsType> NewsTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRole>()
            .HasMany(e => e.AspNetUsers)
            .WithMany(e => e.AspNetRoles)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles").MapLeftKey("RoleId").MapRightKey("UserId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
            .HasMany(e => e.AspNetUserClaims)
            .WithRequired(e => e.AspNetUser)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
            .HasMany(e => e.AspNetUserLogins)
            .WithRequired(e => e.AspNetUser)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Customers)
            .WithRequired(e => e.AspNetUser)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Organisations)
            .WithRequired(e => e.AspNetUser)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Customers)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Organisation)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>()
            .HasMany(e => e.InternationalOffices)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Organisation)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<NewsType>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Customers)
            .WithRequired(e => e.NewsType)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your model and your entity relation (DbSet configuration)?

Comment: Please see the original thread. I've now added to it. I think this is what youre after

Comment: I guess you have a strongly typed view here. Could you please let us know what `model` is your view bound to? Does that model entity have a property for `username`? Ideally, it is better to use a viewmodel to bind to your view instead of a database model.

Comment: Its bound to Organisation. This was generated using the steps in my first sentence and wasnt something i did manually

Answer (score 0):

As your view was binded with `Organization` class and it does not have a `UserName` property, you nedd to use navagation properties to be able to show it on your view.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserID, "Username", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AspNetUser.UserName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserID)
        </div>
    </div>
```

If `Organization.AspNetUser` is null then you need to use `.Include()` method to return it from the databse on your EF query.

```
_db.Organizations.Include(i => i.AspNetUser).FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == idVariable);
```

You can see more about related data in EF on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data